# how to calculate total price in gridview in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview in ASP.NET,In that gridview there is one column of total price.I want to show to total price of all rows below the gridview and also if i will update or delete any row then it should update that total computed price.
Can anyone please help in this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: post some code what you have tried

Comment: Gridview **RowDataBound** event will solve your problem. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx). Similar tutorials are available on web you just have to search it on [Google](https://www.google.co.in/).

Answer (score 0):

The HTML Markup consists of an ASP.Net GridView. The ShowFooter property is set to true so that the GridView’s Footer Row is displayed.
Paging has been enabled for the GridView and OnPageIndexChanging event handler has been assigned.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true"
OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" ShowFooter="true">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderID" HeaderText="Order ID" ItemStyle-Width="60" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product Name" ItemStyle-Width="210" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" ItemStyle-Width="60" DataFormatString="{0:N2}"
        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

code behind.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.BindGrid();
    }
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    string query = "SELECT TOP 30 OrderID,";
    query += "(SELECT ProductName FROM Products WHERE ProductID = details.ProductId) ProductName,";
    query += "(Quantity * UnitPrice) Price";
    query += " FROM [Order Details] details";
    query += " ORDER BY OrderID";
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();

                    //Calculate Sum and display in Footer Row
                    decimal total = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(row => row.Field<decimal>("Price"));
                    GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[1].Text = "Total";
                    GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                    GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[2].Text = total.ToString("N2");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tripurari,Thanks for your answer, but the sum which i want that is gridview column and there is one more div in which i need to show the sum,that div is outside to the gridview,and also i am using entity framework.

Comment: create one object & store total in that object and display below to grid.      protected void GridView1_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            //Check if the current row is datarow or not
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                //Add the value of column
                totalvalue += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Quantity"));
            }
        }